# How to split a Json tag to dataframe in python

Tags: python, json, dataframe

I am new to the python world. I am fetching the below JSON through API and I want to process and convert it into a data frame.

```
{
    "events": [
        {
            "labels": [],
            "links": [
                {
                    "href": "https://context/323472912?per_page=50&timestamp=1590989425549&log_keys=",
                    "rel": "Context"
                }
            ],
            "log_id": "471a-berwf-a899wrcf",
            "message": "gwex [2020-06-01 05:30:20.260] WARN [2344423424234] [Utils] [CFA] User not available, name: George, department: sales, id: 001",
            "timestamp": 1590989425549
        },
        {
            "labels": [],
            "links": [
                {
                    "href": "https://context/3235933?per_page=50&timestamp=1590989425618&log_keys=",
                    "rel": "Context"
                }
            ],
            "log_id": "039-ad2a-be3f-a84b9cf",
            "message": "gwex [2020-06-01 05:30:21.275] WARN [234478424234] [2344423424234] [Utils] [CFA] User not available, name: Mark, department: marketing, id: 002",
            "timestamp": 1590989425618
        },
    ],
    "leql": {
        "during": {
            
        },
        "statement": 
    },
}
```

```
data = eval(jsonresp.text)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_normalize(data), orient='columns')
```

The above query provided columns as events,leql.during,leql.statement,links. All the data in the "events" tag are populated in one column makes it non-readable.

I want a CSV file that only contains data in the event tag with log_id, message, timestamp as a separate column.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should parse the json with `json.loads()` and then construct a `list` of `dict`s using comprehensions. You can then pass the list into `DataFrame` and call `to_csv` to convert into CSV.

```py
from json import loads
from pandas import DataFrame

DataFrame([
    {k: v for k, v in event.items() if k in ['log_id', 'message', 'timestamp']}
    for event in loads(jsonresp.text)['events']
]).to_csv('out.csv')
```

**NOTE:** This is a compact solution for demonstration purpose. Thus, it is not error prone. You should parse and validate your data carefully.